# 'ascii' codec can't encode character Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, kodi

My Code:

```
import xbmcgui
import xbmcaddon
import urllib, urllib2, re, HTMLParser, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pg_source = ''
req = urllib2.Request('http://rushmore.tv/schedule')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36')

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    pg_source = response.read().decode('utf-8' , 'ignore')
    response.close()
except:
    pass

content = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg_source)
content = BeautifulSoup(soup.find('ul', { 'id' : 'myUL' }).prettify())

print (content.text)
```

I am trying to fix the ascii error I am getting when running this code through Kodi.

When running this code through Kodi, I am getting the following error message.

```
Error Type: <type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'>
Error Contents: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 1447: ordinal not in range(128)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\addons\script.test.test\main.py", line 23, in <module>
print (content.text)
File "<string>", line 7, in write
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 1447: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anyone help me fix this?
Ty

Comment: Have you tried putting encoding information in the header? See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#defining-the-encoding

Comment: I have "# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-" on the first line of my .py file. Is that correct?

Comment: why are you writing print statement? it won't work in kodi. also note that in kodi stable releases up until now they are using python2; and for any other functionalities like beautifulsoup, requests you need to install addon for that too. mostly try to encode string with .encode('utf-8'), if it won't work you can use exception case handling for it.

Comment: Sorry I left print in as I was testing my code in python. I have als installed BS and Requests but still left with the error. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Oh aplogies, ignore that last comment. I was using the print as I need to strip the tags and attributes from the scraped content. This is the only way I know how to do it by using the print content.text option. The scrape works perfectly without the print function but the tags and attributes are there. I just want the plain text.